# Upgrade to Play 2.3.X conflict with Google Guava

Tags: playframework-2.0, ivy, dependency-management

I've just updated my Play application from 2.2.2 to 2.3.
When I start it, I have the following problem :

```
Resolving org.jacoco#org.jacoco.agent;0.6.4.201312101107 ...
[error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = com.google.guava#guava;15.0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = com.google.guava#guava;15.0
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.getArtifacts(IvyNode.java:809)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.getSelectedArtifacts(IvyNode.java:786)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport.setDependencies(ResolveReport.java:235)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:517)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:211)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
```

The stacktrace is not complete to make it short.

When I type `activator dependencies` in the folder of my app, I see that the Guava dependency is imported by Play 2.3.0 but the version is 16.0.1.

To make my application work, I have to add the dependency to Guava 15.0 manually in my `build.sbt` file.

Is there a way to force Ivy to use the most recent version ?
Also, how can I know the dependency that requires Guava in its 15.0 version ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

My `build.sbt` file :

```
organization := "com.company"

name := "web"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4" 

offline := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaWs,
    cache,
    "com.company" %% "play-commons" % "1.0.0",
    "com.company" %% "business-commons" % "1.0.0",
    "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "15.0"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava)

jacoco.settings

parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
```

`play-commons` and `business-commons` are independant Play 2.3.0 projects that I publish locally using the same Scala version.

Comment: Added the content in my question

Comment: Sorry no the exclude does not solve the problem